`git difftool` makes a new gvimdiff window pop up, how can I make it just use vimdiff on the same terminal?
This is my current ~/.gitconfig file.
[user]
    email = ckim@etri.re.kr
    name = Chan Kim
[diff]
[difftool]
    prompt = false
[alias]
    d = difftool
    s = "!f() { rev=${1-HEAD};git difftool $rev^ $rev; }; f"
[color]
    diff = auto
[log]
    follow = true

When I type in git d file.txt (see alias) I see the gvimdiff window pops up with the file difference between the repository and my local directory for file.txt. But I used to see the difference in vimdiff window in the same terminal, not a separate gvimdiff window. How can I do this? (I once set vimdiff correctly but somehow I messed it up with tweaking..)

Based on the info in this question I have to ask what does this have to do with Ubuntu?

Does it make a difference if you use d = difftool -t vimdiff or d = difftool --no-gui?

@steeldriver Oh, Thans! setting `d = difftool -t vimdiff' does the trick. (if you add your comment as an answer, I'll select it.)

From steeldriver’s comment:
[alias]
    d = difftool -t vimdiff

Or perhaps:
[alias]
    d = difftool --no-gui

